# Copy User Mappings for SQL Logins using SQLCMD - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to directly copy the **User Mapping** from one SQL Server login to another using SQLCMD?

In **SQL Server Management Studio** Object Explorer | **(local)** | **Security** | **Logins**, Right-Click a user (e.g: BUILTIN\Administrators | **User Mapping**, I'm looking for a way to copy all the related information in that window from one account to a newly created one.

The main reason I need to use SQLCMD is I'm looking to place this in a script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using sp_MSforeachdb to do this - it executes a SQL script against all databases defined in master. Your code is going to look something like the following:

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB ' ---SCRIPT HERE ---'
```

The script to copy permissions from one user to another is a bit long for here, but an example that I found is here: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/scripting_permissions_in_sql_server_2005.htm

If you save that in a .sql script, then run it using SQLCMD or in SSMS, you should see what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Excellent... I'll give this a test run and edit this comment with the result. Thanks! I wish I had the reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: Please don't use sp_msForEachDB, it's undocumented and buggy.http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx